# boost::gregorian::date constructor with Warning C4244

Tags: c++, boost

This code snippet works well on my test project. But it compiles with warnings on my working project

```
auto current_date = boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day();
const auto nMinYear = current_date.year(); const auto nMonth = current_date.month(); const auto nDay = current_date.day();
const auto nMinYear1 = nMinYear + 1;
boost::gregorian::date holidayDate1(nMinYear1, nMonth, nDay);
```

at the line of holidayDate1 construction.

> Warning   C4244   'argument': conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'unsigned
> short', possible loss of data

My test project is on boost-1.72 and working project on 1.75, both are on Visual Studio 2019.

And I tried using grep_year to wrap nMinYear1 -- `holidayDate1(grep_year(nMinYear1 ))` -- it doesn't compile.

Edit:

I just tried a forced casting can work around it,

```
boost::gregorian::date holidayDate1((unsigned short)nMinYear, (unsigned short)nMonth, (unsigned short)nDay);
```

But I don't understand why the warning happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of

```
nMinYear + 1
```

will be an `unsigned int` due to implicit widening of the terms in that expression. So `nMinYear1` is a `const unsigned int`, and the compiler emits a warning when that's used in the `boost::gregorian::date` constructor.

```
decltype(nMinYear) nMinYear1 = nMinYear + 1;
```

is a fix.